# Share memory of two objects in pygame

Tags: memory, pygame, share

I am writing a game where i have a Tank and every tank can shoot bullets. And both Tank and Bullet class have coordinates and direction. And when we shoot a bullet it gets the coordinates of the tank, but when I change the coordinates of the bullet in the `move` method, the coordinates of the tank change also. How can I avoid this memory sharing, without making a lot of variables ?

```
class Tank:

    def __init__(self, coords, direction):
        self.coords = coords
        self.direction = direction
        self.bullet = None

    def shoot_bullet(self):
        self.bullet = Bullet(coords, direction)

class Bullet:

    def __init__(self, coords, direction):
        self.coords = coords
        self.direction = direction

    def _move(self):
         self.coords[0] += 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `coords` is a `list`. So when you pass the list from `Tank` to `Bullet`, you operate on a single `list`, thus a change will be "visible" inside `Tank` *and* `Bullet`.

Either copy that `list`:

```
def shoot_bullet(self):
    self.bullet = Bullet(self.coords[:], self.direction)
```

or use another datastructure, like a `tuple` or, since you use pygame, a `Rect`.